# How to export the zabbix history data with null?

Tags: zabbix

I want to draw the chart using zibbix data and my chart library, but I have some problems. Zabbix history get API doesn`t give any data when the monitoring target is off. As an example, I want to use this data for drawing my chart.

```
data [null, 2, null, null, 5, 6]
time [t1, t2, t3, t4, t5]
```

But the zabbix API returns the data like this:

```
data [2, 5, 6]
time [t2, t4, t5]
```

I don't know how to change data returned from zabbix to data for chart OR how to get the data from zabbix in the format that I want.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

That's the correct behavoir of the Zabbix API.

You have to decide how to handle the "voids" within your application.
The easiest (and imho correct) way is to ignore the missing values and plot the existing ones, like Grafana does.

To achieve your goal you can do something like this:

- query the item first (`item.get`) and get the `interval` value
- query the history (`history.get`)
- using `interval` as reference, search for "voids" in the history and replace them with anything you want: a zero or a specific object to plot a big red interval that says "missing data"

This is actually ugly :) and of course it works only for items with a simple interval value: if you have custom intervals you need to check for them as well.